# CPLEX gap setting with PULP

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, cplex, pulp

Anyone know how to set the `epgap` parameter for `CPLEX` solver when calling `CMD_CPLEX()` from PULP (python)?

I have tried everything from an options file in the folder to tons of different syntax attempts like:

```
prob.solve(CPLEX_CMD(options = ['epgap = 0.25']))
```

Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you probably know, the `CPLEX_CMD` solver is a wrapper around the [CPLEX interactive](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.7.1/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/homepages/interactiveoptimizercommands.html). To set parameters, you need to use the same syntax that you'd use within the interactive. So, to set the [relative MIP gap tolerance](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.7.1/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/Parameters/topics/EpGap.html) parameter, you'd want to use the following syntax:

```
prob.solve(CPLEX_CMD(options=['set mip tolerances mipgap 0.25']))
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much.  How did you know this?  The documentation is sparse - I searched online for weeks.  Is there a repository to your knowledge with more commands and parameter syntax?

Comment: I had to look at the [source code](https://github.com/coin-or/pulp) and run a few experiments. As you said, the documentation is sparse.

Comment: rkersh,  I searched the source code like you did, I think, for WorkMem [link](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSA5P_12.4.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/User_manual/topics/uss_solveMIP_61.html).

It does not look like PULP support setting that parameter, if I am doing this right - could you confirm? I looked through pulp/src/pulp/solvers.py

Comment: The source code shows us that you can enter any parameter in the `options` list. As I said, you just have to use the syntax that is supported in the CPLEX interactive. So, for [WorkMem](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.7.1/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/Parameters/topics/WorkMem.html), you would add `'set workmem 2048'` to the options list (where 2048 is the number of megabytes).

Comment: Thanks rkersh!  I understand now and will use this method going forward.  Kind regards and thanks again friend.